# Rails Time.now.end_of_month not accounting for leap year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a loop that runs every month and I noticed that my logic is not accounting for leap years.

I've tried:

```
newDate = (Time.now.beginning_of_month.to_date - 2.months) + 3.years
```

and

```
newDate = (Time.now.to_date - 2.months).end_of_month + 3.year
```

and they both return `Sun, 28 Feb 2016`.

Why are they not accounting for leap year and returning Feb 29?

Note: This question was asked on 31st March 2013, the code may behave differently on another day.

Comment: Why the downvotes with no explanation? Seems like a valid question to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the calculation computes the end of month for the current year and then adds 3 years.

`(Time.now.beginning_of_month.to_date - 1.month)` = 28,Feb 2013. Add 3 years and you get 28, Feb 2016.

Try this instead -

```
((Time.now.beginning_of_month.to_date - 1.month) + 3.years).end_of_month
```

BTW, subtracting 2 months takes me to January (its still 31st March here)

Comment: I know the `- 1.month` was just for this question so in a month it will be out of data again too.

Comment: Glad to be of help - true about the one month, maybe worth adding a not else you may see some comments :P